# Sticky system - problems - issues

Tags: php, database, mysqli

it is such that I need to build a system like facebook where you can write something on a poster, but this is how to lookup a database for themselves, and use a database for themselves. but I must have in some way made ​​such that it is the same. What I should have few user database it's image and it is approved image. and the user's name

This her is my **Users Database**

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bruger` (
  `id_bruger` int(200) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rank` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `brugernavn` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `profilbillede` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `profilbillede_godkendt` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `navn` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `efternavn` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `profiltekst` longtext NOT NULL,
  `alder` int(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_bruger`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

This is my **entry database**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `opslag` (
  `id_opslag` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tekst` longtext NOT NULL,
  `id_bruger` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_opslag`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

*How have I try to build it but I do not know if I've done it right,*

```
<table border="0">
            <?php
            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT `tekst`, `id_bruger` FROM `opslag`')) { 
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->store_result();
                $stmt->bind_result($tekst, $id_bruger);

                while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                        <td><?php echo $tekst;?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                }
                $stmt->close();
            } else {
                echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklæringen: ' . $mysqli->error;
            }
            ?>
            </table>
```

What I need from the user system is

**profilbillede**

**profilbillede_godkendt**

**brugernavn**

Feel free to ask if there is more you want to know about this?

*Hope you can help me*

Jesper - **Danmark**

Comment: looks like you are selecting rows from completely different table..

Comment: It do I, but how else would I do it if it was?

Comment: so you want profilbillede

profilbillede_godkendt

brugernavn is that all ?

Comment: Yes and then I also get down from posting database. or what to call it.

Comment: It is because I only need to retrieve user infomation from database. and I will not use anything out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you should use the following query instead of the one you have there

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT `profilbillede`, `profilbillede_godkendt`, `brugernavn` FROM `bruger`')
```

And your bind statement to this

```
$stmt->bind_result($profilbillede, $profilbillede_godkendt, $brugernavn);
```

Comment: Well how should I build it so if the user no 1 has just written something on notice as to the show but then also get the infomation from the user database.